# ActiveAdmin: around_filter giving "undefined method" for my filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to add an around_filter to a controller in ActiveAdmin. I get an undefined method error when I try to add the filter. Example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
  controller do
    around_filter :my_filter

    def my_filter
      yield
    end

  end
end
```

When I try it out, I get:

```
"undefined method `my_filter' for #<Admin::EventsController:0x0000010de3a798>"
```

My project is using Rails 3, if that's relevant. What am I missing here?

*Update:* This was due to a very silly syntax error. Rather than something like the above, I had misplaced my method definition, something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
  controller do
    around_filter :my_filter
    # lots of stuff here...
  end

  def my_filter
    yield
  end
end
```

so I was declaring the around filter, but defining it outside the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter method should be inside controller

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
  controller do
    around_filter :my_filter
    # lots of stuff here...

    def my_filter
      yield
    end
  end
end
```